# OpenVPN - Understand the routing table + How to route only the traffic to a specific ip via the VPN

Tags: routing, openvpn

I'm connecting to a VPN service using OpenVPN and everything works fine.
Once I connect these are the rules that automatically are set:

```
root@linux:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:AA:1B:01:AC:FB  
          inet addr:192.168.1.201  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:46867 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29742 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37977382 (36.2 MiB)  TX bytes:5098121 (4.8 MiB)
          Interrupt:16 

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.7.7.126  P-t-P:10.7.7.125  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5817 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:31366374 (29.9 MiB)  TX bytes:308591 (301.3 KiB)

root@linux:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.7.7.125      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
5.120.121.114   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.7.7.1        10.7.7.125      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.7.7.125      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.7.7.125      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Here is what I understand:

- my local IP address is 192.168.1.201
- local gateway is 191.168.1.1
- 5.120.121.114 is the VPN public ip
- tun0 is the VPN tunnel, my machine has 10.7.7.126 as address
- 10.7.7.125 is the p-t-p address I understand is the other "end" of the VPN

Regarding the routing table I understand that:

- by default all traffic is sent via 10.7.7.125 on interface tun0 (but why that mask?)
- 10.7.7.1 is reachable via tun0
- public ip of vpn is reachable via eth0

I don't understand the second default gateway, this is the default when the vpn is not active, is it simply bypassed?

What about the 10.7.7.1? looks like it is the gateway of the vpn...

Why the destination 128.0.0.0?

OpenVPN automatically creates all these rules. But based on what are those created?

I cannot control the server side of the VPN but only the client configuration.

Now what if I would like to:

- force all traffic to 216.58.213.174 to go via VPN tun0 and have all the rest going through eth0?
- can I have it established automatically when starting the VPN?

Thank you for your suggestion and support in understanding this.

KR, 
dk

EDIT:

```
root@linux:~# ip route list
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.125 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
5.152.210.249 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
10.7.7.1 via 10.7.7.125 dev tun0 
10.7.7.125 dev tun0  src 10.7.7.126 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.125 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.201
```

Comment: Just my 2 cents: Use `ip route list` to get a better view of your routes. Also, because ifconfig and route are on it´s road to deprecation on LInux...

Answer (score 18):

> I don't understand the second default gateway, this is the default when the vpn is not active, is it simply bypassed?

This is one of OpenVPN's hacks to route traffic through your tunnel while maintaining your default gateway.  The 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 routes take precedence over the 0.0.0.0/0 route since they are more specific while still matching all addresses.  Search for "def1" in the OpenVPN documentation for more detail

> What about the 10.7.7.1? looks like it is the gateway of the vpn...

Probably, yes

> OpenVPN automatically creates all these rules. But based on what are those created?

They are probably pushed from the server.  I can provide more information if you can provide the output from your client while it's starting along with your configuration file

> I cannot control the server side of the VPN but only the client configuration.

Yep, but the client is highly configurable such that you can override pretty much anything the server wants your client to do.  Still, you'll need to meet your providers basic requirements in order to connect.  You should also check your providers "Terms of Use" to make sure you don't end up pissing them off.

> Now what if I would like to:
>
> force all traffic to 216.58.213.174 to go via VPN tun0 and have all the rest going through eth0?

Yep, include "route 216.58.213.174 255.255.255.255 10.7.7.125" in your config.  That should setup your desired route.  You should be able to keep your other routes in place by removing the "redirect-gateway" option from your configuration

> can I have it established automatically when starting the VPN?

yes, see above

All of the options I've described and more can be found in OpenVPN's online documentation.  https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage

Comment: Many, many thank you's!!! I have spent days rummaging through network minutia trying to understand the cute little trick with the 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1.  In the end I merely had to add a route that's completely redundant except when VPN is enabled.

Comment: Is it possible to do "selective routing" if I am using SSTP VPN? I want the normal browsing traffic to go through my local network and all the office related intranet/git stuffs go through VPN route.

Comment: @sameerpradhan yes, there is a configuration setting you can use to do this.  after you connect just make sure that there are no /1 routes and the right routes for your "office" traffic are in place.

Comment: Great answer, one additional nuance: my client config was not using `redirect-gateway` so I could not remove it. Instead I added `route-nopull` which did the job in combination with the new `route` line.